# How do you detect two fingers to draw two separate circles?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create the following code to detect two fingers and have it track the movement with representations of different colored circles. However, I'm unsure how to have more than one circle working.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MyExtendedView extends View {

    static int touchDoneCounter = 2;

    static String DEBUG_TAG = "CUSTOM_VIEW_INFO";

    float x=0, y=0;

    // The constructor is called first
    public MyExtendedView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(ctx, attrs);

        // Set the background color to black
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    // This method is called before the view is drawn first, on screen rotation and when forceredraw is called
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        Paint g = new Paint();
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);


        // draw the circle where the touch occurs. At start, x and y are zero so the circle is drawn on top right
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 75f, p);



    }



    // This is called when a touch is registered
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

        // logging the kind of event we got
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: { // a pointer was moved
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                break;
            }
        }
        //1.5 at this point we re-draw the circle where the touch occurred
        redrawViewWithCircle(event);

        return true;
    }


    public void redrawViewWithCircle(MotionEvent event) {

        // Get index
        int index = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);

        // Get coordinates for circle center. Set the instance variables.
        this.x = (int)MotionEventCompat.getX(event, index);
        this.y = (int)MotionEventCompat.getY(event, index);

        // Force the view to redraw.
        this.postInvalidate();

    }

}
```

I think I need to have the an Index and and ID, but I'm unsure where that should be placed. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Each finger that touches will have a separate id and index.  Indexes go 0...n (where n is the number of fingers down right now), ids can go higher and have gaps (in case of a lifted finger).  For your app, keep track of all the x and y positions via event.getX(index) and event.getY(index) and add them to a list of Points.  Then when you draw, draw a circle at each point in the list.  For simplicity you can simply clear and rebuild the list each touch for now, since I'm not 100% sure what effect you want in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. At the moment, I'm trying to have the app recognize whenever I use two fingers (rather than one) and track both of the fingers movement with a separate circle of different colors (a yellow circle for one finger and a green one for the other). Am I not keeping track of x and y positions with this.x and this.y?

Comment: You are of the first index. But if you have multiple fingers down, you have multiple xs and ys

Comment: Also which finger is the first index changes

Comment: So rather than having just x and y, I should create 2 other x and y variables? I should then use those to track the second circle upon drawing that right? Also since indices change, and I want the circle to stay on the screen, should I use getPointerId?

Comment: I'd make a List<Point> instead of making multiple other variables.  That reduces the number of variables, keeps the x and y data together, and scales up to 3, 4, or more fingers.